# Android Layout Fill_Parent Problem

Tags: android, layout, fill

I am fairly new to android and am having some problems with a layout. Below is an approximation of what I want the layout to look like. (I would like the list to be below the screen at first so that the user can scroll down to see it.) However my code as it currently stands makes all of the views on the left only take up a quarter the screen instead of half, as depicted, even though I have all widths set to fill_parent.

Also, this layout seems to mess up the coordinate system on my custom view. Normally this wouldn't be much of an issue, but in this case I am using that view to draw a picture and the picture ends up in the wrong place. Does anybody have any idea how to resolve these issues? [image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771949/layout-problem-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the XML file you are using? This would be helpful. Also, the coordinate system of a View does not change based on the layout.